# Error when calling a function from smart contract

Tags: web3.py

I was trying to call the balanceOf function in web3.py and I ran into a problem. I started getting this: "web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and
chain synced?" error when I called the balanceOf method. I called the method like this:

```
contract.functions.balanceOf("0x174dE9daF56Aa0399870c31AAc5209a8D7E88Ee2").call()
```

and from what I saw on the internet this seemed okay, but I removed the line and the error stopped occuring, so what is the fix to this problem

Answer (score 0):

For each of the function defined in the abi there is a defined return type. For the `balanceOf` method normally a `uint256` is expected (at least for most token standards). The error indicates that the value returned cannot be parse into a `uint256`.

This can happen if the contract at the address does not implement the method or implements it with a different return type or if there is no contract at the specified address.

To provide more info it would be good to know what address your `contract` instance is linked to.

Comment: An example for these can be found on the web3py repo: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/176